# Wordpress : admin-ajax.php 400 bad request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I currently using Oxygen Builder in Wordpress, I wanna make link when I click on that, the right column div is loaded with another page using AJAX, and I very very noob in AJAX (sorry for it). So, I follow the tutorial

from this site :
https://sridharkatakam.com/how-to-dynamically-load-posts-on-click-using-ajax-in-genesis/
and this site : https://wpmudev.com/blog/load-posts-ajax/.

Combined their code together because it might be appropriate with my goal, because in sridhar's site load the post not page. FYI, in the oxygen builder, I load the page title (link) and the whole page using Easy Post which is same to a repeater. Then, the Easy Post is inside the Column which divided 2 into 50:50 of size. The left column shows the link which when clicked the right column is loading the whole page.

Here's the screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

Then here's my goal looks like :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZRiiVQN3d4

So, here's the code i wrote :

**PHP (inside the left column of easy post)**

```
printf( '<div id="ajaxlinks"><a href="%s" class="post-link" data-id="%s">%s</a></div>',
esc_url( get_the_permalink() ),
get_the_ID(),
esc_html( get_the_title() )
);
```

**PHP (inside the left column of easy post)**

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'ajax-loadpage',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-loadpage.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    '1.0',
    true
);

wp_localize_script(
    'ajax-loadpage',
    'ajaxloadpage',
    array(
        'ajaxurl'       => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    )
);
```

**Function.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax-loadpage', 'ajax-load-page' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax-loadpage', 'ajax-load-page');
function ajax-load-page() {
echo get_bloginfo( 'title' );
die();
}
```

**AJAX-loadpage.js (I put in the JS folder according to the Tutorial)**

```
(function ($) {

$(document).on( 'click', '#ajaxlinks a', function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxloadpage.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        action: 'ajax-loadpage'
    },
    success: function( result ) {
        alert( result );
    }
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

**Then, the formula returned to : (EDIT)**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

**EDIT 2 :**
**I made some change with the JS to test, and it still return to 400**

**Does any webmaster here know how to save my insomnia? Give me a miracle stackoverflow thank you so much.**

Comment: First of all `div a` targets pretty much every single link on the entire page. You'll want to add an id to the <div> and use that instead. Next, the error clearly states the problem: you're trying to send `page: page` as AJAX parameter, but `page` isn't defined anywhere. Since you backend doesn't seem to be using the parameter, you can simply remove that line.

Comment: Can you edit the code in your question with the changes you made? Also make sure your site is actually using the changed script. You might have to delete the cache.

Comment: Chris G : the question just edited, and this is the link to my frontend https://merapifarmery.com/experiment/?swcfpc=1

Comment: There's a pretty blatant syntax error in your functions.php; the second line is missing `');`

Comment: There are jQuery errors as well. You have extraneous `beforeSend` and `success` functions outside of your ajax call.

Comment: It's really really frustating to solve this 400 bad request on admin-ajax.php

Comment: Try changing from function name from 'ajax-load-page' to 'ajax_load_page'. And then adjust your action calls. Some instances of PHP, or all potentially, do not allow dashes in function names. It's likely that this error is causing WP not to find the referenced function on request.